# How to sort objects according to string date in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, date-parsing, date

I am creating an android application where I need to sort objects according to date. The date is stored as a `String` in Customer Object. How can I do it?

I have already tried it using the `Collection.sort()` method but with no success.

```
public static Comparator<Customer> dateNewOld = new Comparator<Customer>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
           DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           try
           {
               return f.parse(o2.date).compareTo(f.parse(o1.date));
           }
           catch (ParseException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return 0;
       }
   };
```

I expect the output to be sorted ArrayList but it doesn't get sorted according to date.

My Date Format is `19.Jul.2019`, but it’s giving me Unparseable Exception.

Comment: Please provide a full example, the data and your code for sorting are not there.

Comment: Code seems to be fine. By how much your dates are different. Are they different by days and months ?

Comment: If you put the date in format year/month/date, that may make it easier to sort.

Comment: They are different by days.Its in dd/MM/yy format

Comment: Well, I suggest you convert the format you got to the format that leans itself to sorting.

Comment: Or you can use Java LocalDate and it can do the work for you.

Comment: How can i use LocaleDate

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("12/02/2019", dtf);
        LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("12/03/2019", dtf);
        
        System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));`

Comment: i Just saw that its Giving me Unparceable Exception

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Tip: Rewrite your `Customer` class to hold a `LocalDate` object rather than a mere string.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from your exception. It will tell us a whole lot about what’s going wrong.

Comment: [I downvoted because your question is missing exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) and [because lacking a minimal, reproducible example (formerly known as an MCVE) makes it hard to answer](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `LocalDate` as your property

The best solution is to alter your `Customer` class to use `LocalDate` class as the type of your property.

Tip: Use a more descriptive name for your member fields that just `date`.

```
public class Customer {
    public LocalDate firstContact ; 
    …
}
```

Now your [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) becomes quite simple, as the `LocalDate` class already implements the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and its [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method.

```
public static Comparator< Customer > CustomerComparator = new Comparator< Customer >() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare( Customer c1 , Customer c2 ) {
        return ( c1.firstContact.compareTo( c2.firstContact ) ) ;
    }
};
```

If you cannot change the data type of your class property, see the correct [Answer by Ezequiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114993/642706).

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

Use the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome legacy classes (`java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`). An implementation of the modern classes come with Android 26 and later.

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

`LocalDate` represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
package sortdates;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SortDates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Comparator<MyData> comparator = Comparator.comparing(myData -> LocalDate.parse(myData.date, formatter));
        List<MyData> set = getMyData().stream()
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        set.forEach(myData -> System.out.println(myData.date));
    }

    private static Collection<MyData> getMyData() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new MyData("01/01/2000"),
                new MyData("01/02/2000"),
                new MyData("03/01/2002"),
                new MyData("04/06/2001")
                );
    }

    public static class MyData{
        String date;

        public MyData(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I added some explanatory text to your Answer. Stack Overflow is meant to be more than a snipped collection. You are expected to have some explanation of your code, its motivation, and its details.

Answer (score 1):

> ArrayList sorting String_Dates and avoiding duplicates on adding.

Adding a new example to @Ezequiel post.

```java
public class ArrayListSet {
    static ArrayList<String> list =  new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputDatess = "15.10.2020,11.10.2020,12.10.2020,12.10.2020,18.10.2020,13.10.2020,14.10.2020,11.10.2020,"
                + "15.10.2020,15.10.2020,15.10.2020,16.10.2020,17.10.2020,18.10.2020,19.10.2020,20.10.2020,10.10.2020";
        
        String[] dates = inputDatess.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            listCustomAdd(dates[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("ArrayList with Custom Funciton for Add:\n"+list);
        
        ArrayList<String> listSorted = getSortedDatesStrList(list.stream());
        System.out.println("Sorted ArrayList:\n"+listSorted);
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> getSortedDatesStrList(Stream<String> stream) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(myData -> LocalDate.parse(myData, formatter));
        ArrayList<String> sortedList = (ArrayList<String>) stream
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return sortedList;
    }
    public static void listCustomAdd(String dateStr) {
        if( !list.contains(dateStr) )
            list.add(dateStr);
    }
}
```

---

Example with Customed ArrayList to sort and avoid duplicates:

```java
public class CustomArrayListSet {
    //static ArrayList<String> predefinedList =  new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayListCustomStr<String> customList = new ArrayListCustomStr<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputDatess = "15.10.2020,11.10.2020,12.10.2020,12.10.2020,18.10.2020,13.10.2020,14.10.2020,11.10.2020,"
                + "15.10.2020,15.10.2020,15.10.2020,16.10.2020,17.10.2020,18.10.2020,19.10.2020,20.10.2020,10.10.2020";
        
        String[] dates = inputDatess.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            customList.add(dates[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Custom ArrayList with override Add Function:\n"+customList);
        
        customList.sortDatesStrList();
        System.out.println("Sorted ArrayList:\n"+ customList );
    }
}
class ArrayListCustomStr<T> implements Set<T> {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            buffer.append(entries.get(i));
            if ( (i+1) < entries.size() ) buffer.append(", ");
        }
        buffer.append("]");
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    public void sortDatesStrList() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(myData -> LocalDate.parse(myData, formatter));
        ArrayList<String> sortedList = (ArrayList<String>) entries.stream()
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        entries = sortedList;
    }
    private ArrayList<String> entries;
    // Simple constructor using an array list for its entries.
    public ArrayListCustomStr() {
        super();
        entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }
    public void clear() {
        entries.clear();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return entries.isEmpty();
    }
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return entries.toArray();
    }
    public boolean add(Object o) {
        // Ignore existing entries to ensure Set interface contract
        if (entries.contains(o))
            return false;

        return entries.add((String) o);
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return entries.contains(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return entries.remove(o);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean addAll(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection c) {
        return entries.addAll(c);
    }
    public boolean containsAll(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection c) {
        return entries.containsAll(c);
    }
    public boolean removeAll(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection c) {
        return entries.removeAll(c);
    }
    public boolean retainAll(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection c) {
        return entries.retainAll(c);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return (Iterator<T>) entries.iterator();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object[] toArray(Object[] a) {
        return entries.toArray(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

    System.out.println("date1 : " + sdf.format(date1));
    System.out.println("date2 : " + sdf.format(date2));

    if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
        System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate it with an example

Comment: All you have to do is change the format string. This is as straight forward as it gets. @Anaskhan

Comment: As in the example, did you try with `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
`

Comment: I still am unable to figure it out.Can you please change the example i gave for Ascending Order

Comment: My Date Format is 19.Jul.2019 , but its giving me Unparceable Exception

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Comparing o2 with o1 will sort your list in descending order.

You can use Collections.sort() as well as list.sort()

I have created a test class with a customer object.
Hope this example will help.

```
package project;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class SortTest
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add( new Customer( 1, "21/07/2019" ) );
        list.add( new Customer( 2, "19/06/2019" ) );
        list.add( new Customer( 3, "20/07/2019" ) );

        Collections.sort( list, dateNewOld );
        //list.sort( dateNewOld );

        print( list );
    }

    public static Comparator<Customer> dateNewOld = new Comparator<Customer>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare( Customer o1, Customer o2 )
        {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
            try
            {
                return f.parse( o2.date ).compareTo( f.parse( o1.date ) );
            }
            catch ( ParseException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };

    private static void print( List<Customer> list )
    {
        for ( Customer customer : list )
        {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }

    static class Customer
    {
        final int id;
        final String date;

        Customer( int id, String date )
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Customer{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with how you compare the two Strings, here is a working example(**in ascending order**).

```
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
dateList.add("22/05/1995");
dateList.add("22/01/1995");
dateList.add("22/01/1994");
Comparator<String> dateNewOld = new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
      return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
dateList.sort(dateNewOld);
System.out.println(dateList);
```

PS: My guess is that your code is not sorting because of `return 0` inside the comparator. Maybe your code is throwing an exception and you haven't seen console!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).